# On a Samsung NP550P5C-S01IN, unable to adjust brightness with fn keys after installing Nvidia drivers.

Tags: 13.04, nvidia

The problem came up after installing Nvidia graphics driver on my Samsung NP550P5C-S01IN laptop. I'm currently using Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

change this line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Finally run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot your computer.

Comment: tried but it couldn't resolve  my problem ..